# Tomcat cluster with no serializable object

Tags: apache, tomcat, cluster-computing, session-replication

I have set up Tomcat  cluster, behiind Apache Httpd server, with 2 nodes. I read  the Tomcat documentation at [Tomcat cluster how to](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/cluster-howto.html#Cluster_Basics) and the first requirement is:"All your session attributes must implement java.io.Serializable". I've done and session replication, failover mechanism seems to work. Now I'm using a framework for Web app develop and it seems that the object classes that are stored in the session don't implement Serializable. I'm looking for a workaround to solve this problem in the simplier manner. I've read a lot of questions/answer but not solution so far. Any idea? Tomcat version 7.0.76. Thank you.

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/rover886/tomcat-pysession-server#tomcat-pysession-server-with-zero-or-no-change-in-java-code) library by which Tomcat cluster is no more needed.

Comment: Talk to the framework authors? This seems like a very common use-case, and implementing `Serializable` doesn't seem that difficult. If you have large amounts of data in your session, you may want to reconsider whether or not session-replication is a good idea.